# using SimpleHTTPServer and it's result

Tags: python

I'm very new with python, so sorry for the stupid question.
i'm trying to set up a http server, so I took the following code from : https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html
put it in a test.py file, and just ran : python test.py
When I went to localhost:8000 I saw many directories..
why and why doesn't it show my print "serving at port 8000"  ?
thanks

```
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer

PORT = 8000

Handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)

print "serving at port", PORT
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
serving at port 8000
```

will be displayed as output on your *terminal*, not in an HTML page.

As for `SimpleHTTPServer` it just serves whatever pages you access using the directory from which it was executed as the root directory. If you do not request a specific page, a listing of files in that directory is shown.

Rather than copying the file from the standard library, you can just run it using the `-m` Python option:

```
$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The print in this statement is intended to be used to indicate to the runner of the script in a console that the server was started on "PORT". The directory structure you're seeing when you navigate to http://localhost:8000 is generally what a http server will display when there is no index page. Try creating a index.html in the same directory as your python script with some text in it such as

```
Hello, world!
```

And then refresh your web browser.

The [do_GET()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html#SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.do_GET) part of the SimpleHTTPServer documentation speaks about this more.

Comment: I added an index.html file to the same directory, in it i wrote "hello" .. still shows me directories...